# Object autoreleased too many times

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NIDropDown *rangeDropDown;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NIDropDown *filterDropDown;

self.rangeDropDown = [[[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn height:f dataSource:rangeArr imageData:nil direction:@"down"]autorelease];

self.filterDropDown = [[[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn height:f dataSource:filterArr imageData:nil direction:@"down"]autorelease];
```

In these lines , Object autoreleased too many times was given to me . 
In other words,As Follow:

1,Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count

2, Object was autoreleased but has a +0 retain count.

NIDropDown: https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown

noArc,while NIDropDown was Arc.

I tried it in other way.

```
@interface SelectorView(){
    NIDropDown *_rangeDropDown;
    NIDropDown *_filterDropDown;
}

 _rangeDropDown = [[[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn height:f dataSource:rangeArr imageData:nil direction:@"down"]autorelease];

 _filterDropDown = [[[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn height:f dataSource:filterArr imageData:nil direction:@"down"]autorelease];

or 

_rangeDropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn height:f dataSource:rangeArr imageData:nil direction:@"down"];

 _filterDropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:btn height:f dataSource:filterArr imageData:nil direction:@"down"];
```

Both was potential leak of an object .
1:Method returns an Object-C object with a+1 retain count.

2:Object leaked:allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1.

But,It was not crashed.  What  should I  do  for avoiding these potential leaks?

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC?

Comment: @godel9 At the beginning of the project, I didn't use the arc. , it has been completed.

Comment: Also, are you overriding `dealloc`?

Comment: Seems to me you're missing an init.

Comment: @HotLicks If you look up the `NIDropDown` project on GitHub, the `showDropDown` method calls `[super init]` and returns `self`. The method should definitely be renamed to `initWith...`, but I don't know if that's causing the problem.

Comment: @godel9 - It very likely confuses the analyzer.  Whoever wrote it that way should get ten lashes with a wet character string.

Comment: Without looking at the source for the methods, I wonder if the OP miscoded things and it should be `[[NIDropDown showDropDown:btn ...`.  Certainly that would be more consistent with standards.  (Gotta wonder what other "treats" are in store for a package that ignores so obvious a standard.)

Comment: (And looking at the source it's just plain wrong. `self.table = (UITableView *)[super init];` -- How does that work?)

Comment: Wow... I missed that one. This library looks like a mini-disaster.

Comment: Yeah, my advice to the OP is to not use that package.

Comment: @Hot Licks ,In fact, self.table = (UITableView *)[super init]; I have no idea .it doesn't work ,right ?

Comment: It works, but quite by accident.  Whoever wrote that code obviously didn't know what he was doing.  There are most certainly other more serious bugs hidden in the code.

Comment: Well,I will finish it myself .